# Installing Ubuntu onto MacBook Pro via USB

Tags: installation, usb, mac, refit

I am new to this forum, and to Ubuntu. But I am trying to get it installed onto my MacBook Pro (late 2009 - with an installed Samsung SSD).

I have attempted to follow the tutorial on the Ubuntu website:

[www.ubuntu.com - How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

But it doesn't seem to work. I have rEFIt installed as well. I have partitioned my SSD into my main one (Macintosh HD), and a new one (~30GB, Ubuntu). I then followed the tutorial through, but it still doesn't seem to work. I have a few questions (parts I might have messed up on):

1. I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04, 64 bit. Is this OK?
2. On Step 3, I renamed the new image so that it ended in ".img" instead of ".dmg", which it converted to. I did this because the rest of the tutorial referred to a file ending in ".img". Was this what I was supposed to do?
3. When I rebooted and held down the **alt** key nothing but the rEFIt drive (and the Mac recovery drive came up. No Ubuntu drive (partition), and no USB drive, is this supposed to happen? However, when I booted into rEFIt, the USB drive came up, and when I ran it, it came up with a sort of purple screen the a keyboard and accessibility icon in the bottom center of the screen, after this however, it goes black (screen does not turn off).

(4. If I ever do get it installed, will I have to install any drivers for either my Mac harware or my SSD?)

I am currently on Mountain Lion. The reason why I am using a USB drive is because my MacBook Pro keep spitting out anything (except films...really odd) that I put into it. It rejected the Windows installation disk (which I put into test), and it rejected all CDs **and** DVDs which I attempted to burn Ubuntu onto.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try the *Mac* version (64bit perhaps) of Ubuntu (or whatever flavor you wish) available on the main Ubuntu [release](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) page.

Then you put the ISO on the USB drive using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for Mac. Thanks to REFIt or Refind it will work.

Source: [That's The Way You Do It: How To Install Ubuntu 13.04 On A Macbook Air Using USB Drive](http://www.thatsthewayyoudoit.me/2013/04/how-to-install-ubuntu-1304-on-macbook.html)

Comment: The MAC isos have never worked for me. The EFI loader on the regular image does, however. Installation instrunctions as well as grub configuration/SSD optimiaztion/proprietary driver installation are going to differ from Macbook to Macbook. You're better off finding a guide suited to your specific MBP model number. IE. 5,5. 5,3 or 5, 7

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218456